Is it possible to estimate "number of flips" AND "probability of heads" from a coin?
Suppose I have the following situation:

Person 1 flipped a coin $n_1$ times and $z_1$ heads
Person 2 flipped the same coin $n_2$ times and $z_2$ heads
Person 3 flipped the same coin $n_3$ times and $z_3$ heads
etc.

In this situation, it is very easy to estimate the "probability of success" using Maximum Likelihood Estimation based on the Binomial Distribution.
Now, let's say we are only given the following information:

Person 1 got $z_1$ heads
Person 2 got $z_2$ heads
Person 3 got $z_3$ heads
etc.

In this situation, (using Maximum Likelihood Estimation) is it still possible to estimate the "probability of success" when we don't know how many times each person flipped the coin?
Or do we simply not have enough information to proceed?

Say : We got $100$ times heads. If the number of tosses was $100$ , the reasonable estimate of the probability for "heads" is $1$ , if the number of tosses was $10^9$ , we expect an extremely low probability for "heads". So , no , we do not have enough information here.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Assuming that by "probability of success", you mean the probability $\ p_h\ $ of each toss being heads, then  yes, you can  still, at least in theory, use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to estimate it.  The likelihood function
$$
L(p_h,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N)\ed\prod_{i=1}^N{n_i\choose z_i}p_h^{z_i}\big(1-p_h\big)^{n_i-z_i}
$$
is the same, regardless of whether you know the values of the $\ n_i\ $ or not.  The only difference is that you now have $\ N+1\ $ unknown quantities, $\ p_h,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N\ $ to be estimated instead of just $\ p_h\ .$ However the maximum likelihood estimates of $\ p_h,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N\ $ are $\,\hat{p}=1,$$\,\hat{n}_1=z_1,$$\,\hat{n}_2=z_2,$$\,\dots,$$\,\hat{n}_N=z_N\ ,$ and are practically worthless. Thus, while there's sufficient information to obtain a maximum likelihood estimate for $\ p\ ,$ there isn't enough for that estimate to be of any value.
